# Array convert to string in views django

Tags: python, arrays, django, string, python-2.7

i have a array in Django views and i want to convert into comma separated string, to save data into DB field like all in one.

```
array[0] = "Ford";
array[1] = "Volvo";
array[2] = "BMW";
```

i didn't get anything how to do that?
and i need output like this.

```
    sting = "Ford,Volvo,BMW"
```

Comment: The code you have shared doesn't seem to have any relation to the question you have asked

Comment: this may not but i need to convert Array into string is there any way to do thay ?

Comment: [','.join(array)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: this is helpful. and working perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
','.join(your_array)
```

Please mark the solution as valide to avoid all other people to dig in comments...